# Create a scheduled job without specifying End date

Tags: scheduled-job, setup

Is it possible to create a scheduled job without specifying End date?

[image]

I know that this is possible, because, in our org someone already set a scheduled job without specifying the End date.

[image]

When trying to run the following code in anonymous Apex in developer console I got the following error:

```
System.schedule('Update presigne url','0 0 0 ? * SUN', new NEILON.edGeneratePresignedURLSchedulable());
```

[image]

What can I try to do to get rid of it?

Also I am able to schedule the class from UI.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not in the UI; you need to run a [System.schedule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) call in Apex code:

```
System.schedule('JobName','0 0 0 ? * SUN', new JobClassName());
```

You can do this in the Developer Console (click on "Your name" to find it), and click on Debug > Open Execute Anonymous Window.

Please read the documentation for details, but basically the first value is the job name, must be unique, the second value is the Cron Expression to use (this example runs at midnight each Sunday), and the third parameter is an instance of the job controller (in the UI, the "class name").

Comment: What can I try to do in order to get rid from the `Type is not visible` issue?

Comment: @nicedaytoday Your class needs to be "public" in order to use it.

Comment: Ok, got it, thank. But why then can I schedule it from UI? I am updating my question to reflect it.

Comment: @nicedaytoday Okay, that's a "managed package" class. You can't schedule it, because it's restricted. There should be a Visualforce page or something that you would use to schedule it. Normal classes you create you can schedule this way. Schedules in managed classes are things that can typically only be scheduled by the package itself. In other words, nobody in your org scheduled it directly, it was scheduled by managed code.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an end date in the future, up to the year 4000.